# Outlook 2016 VBA - Run Clean Up Folder via code

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to put code into Outlook VBA where I can loop through all my offline folders and run the "Clean Up Folder & Subfolders" menu command on each folder.  I have tried several items and cannot get anything to work.  There is very little online and no working code.  All suggestions point to             Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ThreadCompressFolderRecursive"), but that object does not exist.  Any Ideas?

Comment: Application surely exists. If you post another question provide the code to demonstrate the results. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry the CommandBars object does not exist in the Application object.

Answer (score 0):

Not the Application. Use Inspector or Explorer as required.

```
Sub ExecuteMso_CleanUP()

    Dim objExpl As Explorer

    Set objExpl = ActiveExplorer
    objExpl.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ThreadCompressFolderRecursive")

End Sub
```

Comment: This code will not compile in Outlook 2016.  CommandBars is not an available object in either Active Explorer or Inspector.  In the object browser I see it as part of the Office object, but don't know how to get access to it.

Comment: It is possible there was a change in 2016. This code works in 2013.

Comment: I am guessing there was a change, but cannot find anything that will work.  I tried all kinds of options looking through the object browser, but no luck so far.  Cannot even get an idea to compile.